# Limit of a function given a condition

Tags: limits, functions

if $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+ \frac{1}{f(x)})$ exists.Prove or Disprove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists.

I am totally clueless about this.
I don't know how to start and from where to start.
I tried to find some counter examples but could not get any

Comment: Hint: if $f(x)=2$ or $f(x)=1/2$ then $f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{5}{2}$. Can you use this to come up with a counterexample?

Comment: @kccu I still can't come up with any counter-examples... Does it really not exist?

Comment: According to my hint, if we choose $f(x)$ so that $f(x)=2 $ or $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ for every $x$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}$ will exist and equal $\frac{5}{2}$. Can you find $f(x)$ so that $f(x)=2$ or $f(x)=1/2$ for every $x$ but $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ does not exist? The formula doesn't have to be "nice" - the function will be discontinuous. Try jumping between the two values $2$ and $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Maadhav That will work, but it is nice to let OP come to a solution on their own.

Comment: @kccu Nope.I cannot get to any conclusion from your hint.

Comment: @kccu Do you mean that the function $ f(x)=2 for x is irrational            \newline  \frac{1}{2} for x is irrational $ works?

Comment: @Suraj Yes, that is one of many possible solutions, as it will make $f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}$ the constant $\frac{5}{2}$. So $\lim_{x\to \infty} (f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)})$ exists, but because $f$ keeps jumping between two values, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ does not exist. Another solution would be to let $f(x)$ be $2$ if $x$ is an integer and $\frac{1}{2}$ otherwise. Also there was nothing special about $2$ and $\frac{1}{2}$, we could have used $c$ and $\frac{1}{c}$ for any $c\neq 0$.

Comment: @kccu Thanks a Tonn!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Draw the graph of $g(x) = x+1/x$ for $x>0$ and notice each value in $(1,\infty)$ is taken on twice by $g.$